# How to name column with BCP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created this code in a stored procedure, it works like a charm: but now my software provider asked me to also include column name. Have tried 100 things for hours now always close but never get success. can anyone help me.

Thank you !

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <blablabla>
-- Create date: <2014/04/16>
-- Description: <Export Orders to csv>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[transfertofile]
AS
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @return_value int
IF EXISTS (Select 1 From dbo.temp_updated)
    BEGIN
     DECLARE @sql   varchar (8000)

SELECT @sql ='bcp "Select Detail, SectionRelease, 1, WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.OrderNumber, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.LineNumber, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.ItemNumber, CAST(WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.ActualQuantity AS NUMERIC(10)), WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.UDF01, WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.UDF02, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.PickFrom FROM WMS80.dbo.temp_updated, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail WHERE WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.OrderNumber = WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.OrderNumber" queryout "C:\bcptest.txt" -U user -P password -c -S servername -t,'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql

 --delete at the end
 TRUNCATE TABLE WMS80.dbo.temp_updated


 DECLARE
@TodayDate as varchar(40),
@TodayHour as varchar(40),
@TodayMinu  as varchar(40),
@TodaySeco  as varchar(40),
@NewFileName as varchar(100),
@cmdstr as varchar(128)
SELECT @TodayDate = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112)
SELECT @TodayHour = DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())
SELECT @TodayMinu = DATEPART(mi,GETDATE())
SELECT @TodaySeco = DATEPART(SS,GETDATE())
SELECT @NewFileName = 'ExportOrders' + '_' + @TodayDate + '_' + @TodayHour + '_' + @TodayMinu + '_' + @TodaySeco + '.csv'
print @NewFileName
set @cmdstr='MOVE /Y C:\bcptest.txt C:\'  + @NewFileName  
print @cmdstr
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmdstr

END
else
    BEGIN
        return
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION statement in your bcp query to hardcode the column names into the output file. This means of course you will have to export everything as varchar/string, since every column is going to contain its name in varchar format as a first entry.

```
@sql ='bcp "SELECT 'Detail', 'SectionRelease', '1', 'OrderNumber', 'LineNumber','ItemNumber', 'ActualQuantity', 'UDF01', 'UDF02', 'PickFrom', 'PickingDetail' 
UNION SELECT Detail, SectionRelease, 1, WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.OrderNumber, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.LineNumber, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.ItemNumber, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.ActualQuantity, WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.UDF01, WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.UDF02, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.PickFrom FROM WMS80.dbo.temp_updated, WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail WHERE WMS80.dbo.temp_updated.OrderNumber = WMS80.dbo.PickingDetail.OrderNumber" queryout "C:\bcptest.txt" -U user -P password -c -S servername -t,'
```